# when is WebView's getVideoLoadingProgressView called? No callback while buffering a fullscreen video

Tags: java, android, webview, webchromeclient

When is WebChromeClient's `getVideoLoadingProgressView` called? To what functionality/Use case does it correspond to?

I tried putting a breakpoint on the method and debug the app while a full-screen video was buffering, but this method isn't getting a callback.

Expecting a use case/functionality corresponding to the method mentioned above. A use case such that there is a callback to the method when the functionality is carried out.

Comment: show what you have done so far.include your code here please

Comment: I've just overridden the method and called super method of the same.